# Show image when in viewpoint of browser window

Tags: javascript, optimization, jquery, image

I am working on a web project and am trying to create a way to detect when an image is in viewpoint of the browser window then load/show the image. Since there are some rather large image that are being resize to use a thumbnails, I am trying to take into consideration those that might view it one a mobile device and reduce page loading time. I notice that many site with galleries are doing the same thing.

I create a little script using JavaScript to detect when an `<img />` tag is in view and then take its data attribute value (the URL of the image) and set it's `<img src=""/>` attribute to it.

Is this is an efficient way of doing it or should I just use PHP the create thumbnails?

I have included snippets of the HTML and JavaScript I am using.

**HTML of the image**

```
<img data-image-src="images/c9c191f226c643eabcce6debfe76049d.png" src="" alt="A nify Image" />
```

**JavaScript with jQuery**

```
//Show images when in viewpoint
$(window).on('scroll load',function(){
    //Window width & height
    var viewpointWidth = $(window).width(),
    viewpointHeight = $(window).height(),
    //Document Top pos & Left pos
    documentScrollTop = $(document).scrollTop(),
    documentScrollLeft = $(document).scrollLeft(),
    //Document Positions
    minTop = documentScrollTop,
    maxTop = documentScrollTop + viewpointHeight,
    minLeft = documentScrollLeft,
    maxLeft = documentScrollLeft + viewpointWidth;
    //Loop for each image
    $('.page-content img').each(function(){
        $eleImage = $(this),
        elementOffset = $eleImage.offset();       
        if((elementOffset.top > minTop && elementOffset.top < maxTop) && (elementOffset.left > minLeft &&elementOffset.left < maxLeft)) {
            $(this).attr('src',$(this).data('image-src'));
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: A point (an img) may enter the viewport through window resize, so you would have to handle those events also.

Comment: Thank you, should I add the `onresize` even to jQuery's `.on()` even handler like so `$(window).on('scroll load resize',function(){...}` or go about it a different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Correctness

- You need to handle `resize` events also. Yes, you can add it like : `$(window).on('scroll load resize', ...`
- You are only checking for the visibility of the top/left corner, if you load a large image, scroll right, and then scroll down, you will see the right edges of the `ALT` text of the images, but because their top/left corner is not in viewport, those images will not load. You might want to check if any point of the img box is visible.

### Browser Behavior

- Make sure you have `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` on your document, this will load all images if you miss `doctype` declaration. (for Firefox, Chrome, don't know about others)
- You might want to mark images processed, by adding a class or another data; and do not fiddle with the `src` attributes of the images once they are loaded.

### Javascript related

- Because you miss a `var` before `$eleImage` and `elementOffset`, they pollute global namespace.
- You copy the value of `$(this)` here : `$eleImage = $(this)`, but you keep using `$(this)` below.